# Android freezes on all apps - SD card

Tags: applications, sd-card

My Xiaomi Redmi Note 10 Pro has been troubling me for the last few days.
During usage, the app froze and no new app could be opened again, reboots didn't help.

While troubleshooting I noticed, only that the system itself is working - all settings are accessible and the phone is stable. When I boot without the SD card, most apps and functions do work as long as no data from the SD card is needed.

The SD card is formatted as internal storage. I checked the SD card in the Windows partition manager, there are two partitions which seem to be fine.

All my crucial data is safe but I'm missing some important pictures, which seem to be saved somewhere on the main storage as thumbnails - as these are visible without the SD card in the gallery app.

Do you have a suggestion to extract the thumbnails?
Is there a way to remount the SD card?
Is there a way to export the encryption key and try to decrypt the SD card externally?